# more efficient to create static local objects c++

Tags: c++, object, constructor, local-variables

**Edit:** I know that declaring an object before a loop body is more efficient since it calls the constructor and destructor per function call rather than once per loop iteration. Lets say that objects of type A are more efficient outside a loop body due to this reasoning.

I'm wondering if the following

```
void foo()
{
    static A var;  //A is a class with a constructor
    ...   //stuff done with var
}
```

is more efficient than

```
void foo()
{
    A var;   //A is a class with a constructor
    ...  //stuff done with var
}
```

since the former would call A's constructor and destructor once rather than the latter which does it per call of foo. I ask this question generally across all local objects.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is semantically different. You are comparing two different things. If you don't care about the semantic difference, either one can be faster than the other. If the construction of `A` doesn't do much, e.g., merely initializes an `int` it is quite possible that second version is faster, e.g., because the compiler needs to know if it initialized `var` at run-time and in C++11 the initialization is thread-safe. If the construction of `A` is somewhat involved it is likely that the first version is faster.

The only way to find out for any given application is to measure.

Comment: Well in general if the constructor won't make a difference to the rest of the objects use, then the first would be better (if the constructor is big enough)

Comment: @bathtub no, that is by far not the important difference.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb: Code what you mean (a local object or does it logically need to be shared every call?) and let the compiler worry about optimizations.

I make an exception for constants of non-trivial types. For example, 'static const std::string' is better than 'const std::string' because it saves a dynamic allocation every time. But if the object does not contain dynamic allocations and it is not dozens of bytes in size, make it a local variable.

There is no need to make basic types (such as `const int` or `const char *const`) static for efficiency reasons, although it wouldn't hurt.

As a static object is shared between threads, the compiler may need to check it has not been updated by another thread each time it needs to use it, which cannot be the case for a local variable. So don't assume static will be the "fastest". (How this works depends on your compiler implementation)

Of course you also need to realize how making it static or not may change the behavior of your program. My information above assumes the choice won't.

Comment: So constants which are used every call made static are more efficient. Basically doing this occurred to me when dealing with objects which served as temp objects that would be later pushed to a vector or something along those lines. When in a loop, it was more efficient to construct outside the loop body rather than every iteration. So I figured the same applied to this situtation

Comment: @bathtub I wouldn't worry about it. If it's too slow, you can optimize later. It's better to make a working solution first. Also the compiler can optimize lots of things (especially if A is simple), so it might not make a difference anyway. I mean it might, but wait until it matters.

Answer (score 1):

First make it right, then make it fast. The version with the static variable carries over the value from the previous call; unless you need to retain information across multiple calls, good design calls for setting the variable to a known state, which is what the constructor does. If you don't use the constructor, i.e., you make the variable static, then you have to do something else to get the variable into a known state; that is, you end up calling a function that does what the constructor would have done, but you have more obscure syntax.

Here's a somewhat oversimplified example:

```
void f(int j) {
    static int i = 0;
    i = 0; // reset, because previous call left i with some spurious value
    while (i < j)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

That aside, sharing that variable between calls means that in a multi-threaded program you will have to synchronize all calls to that function, introducing a bottleneck that will almost certainly offset any performance gain from not constructing the object each time it's used.